# How to replace multiple lines between two patterns with content of a file using sed?

Tags: sed, substitution, paragraph

Suppose I have the bellow content in a file
file1.txt:

```
some text ...
...    
begin  
    if somthing is true  
       some text here  
       ...  
    fi 
end  
some text
```

I want to replace text between begin end including begin end with content of 
another file
file2.txt:

```
while read line:  
do  
   some code
done
```

After substitution the file1.txt should be like this
file1.txt:

```
some text ...
...    
while read line:  
do  
   some code
done
some text
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I cant understand your question ...

Comment: do you have some code to add to your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this sed

```
sed -e '/begin/,/end/!b' -e '/end/!d;r file2.txt' -e 'd' file1.txt
```

Sed print each line of the file if option -n is not specified.
Before printing, sed execute the script given by all the -e option given.
The command b in the script tell to sed to end the script at this point.
So the first -e command tell sed to end the script and print the line for all lines not in begin and end.
The second -e command tell sed to print the file file2.txt when it find the line with end.
The third -e command tell sed to delete (not print) the lines from begin to end.

Comment: Wow, this is some serious `sed`. I read the docs and I still don't really get it. Could you break that down a bit?

Comment: @brandones I edit the post for you and try to explain how this work.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/begin/{print;system("cat FIlE2.txt");next} 1' FIlE1.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
some text ...
...
begin
while read line:
do
   some code
done
    if somthing is true
       some text here
       ...
    fi
end
```